# iPhone iOS how to draw text on a CALayer using drawLayer:inContext:?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I have a simple scrolling graph which uses this method to draw itself. I'm looking for a way to add text label to this graph, but cannot find how to do this.

I tried:

```
[@"test" drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]];
```

and I get error messages saying invalid context 0x0. **How do I modify the code below to point the text drawing code to the correct context?**

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)l inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Fill in the background
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, graphBackgroundColor());
    CGContextFillRect(context, layer.bounds);

    // Draw the grid lines
//  DrawGridlines(context, 0.0, 32.0);

    // Draw the graph
    CGPoint lines[64];
    int i;
    // X
    for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        lines[i*2].x = i;
        lines[i*2].y = -(xhistory[i] * 480.0)-10;
        lines[i*2+1].x = i + 1;
        lines[i*2+1].y = -(xhistory[i+1] * 480.0)-10;
    }

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, graphZColor());
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, lines, 64);
}
```

Comment: You could just add a CATextLayer as a sublayer of your layer.

Answer (score 6):

For each thread, UIKit maintains a stack of graphics contexts.  You can get the context that is at the top of the current thread's stack by calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`.

When you use `drawInRect:withFont:`, the string draws itself to the context returned by `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`, so you need to make `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` return the `context` argument of `drawLayer:inContext:` using `UIGraphicsPushContext`.  When you are done drawing, you must then call `UIGraphicsPopContext`.  Thus:

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)l inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context); {
        // Fill in the background
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, graphBackgroundColor());
        CGContextFillRect(context, layer.bounds);
        // etc.
    } UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```